# Line item detail report with subtotaled dollar amounts

Tags: reports, line-items

Our accountants are asking for a report that seems pretty reasonable but I am not finding a civicrm report that will deliver it.  Maybe there's one that does but not obvious, or an extension?

All of our transactions are complex; very few have only one item.  So, the solution needs to be able to group by line item.  We need detail on each transaction, including date received and instrument type.  And each line item needs to be subtotalled.

The closest I've gotten is "Extended Report - Contributions with Price Set data" or "Extended Report - Price Set Line Items".  Both of these will display the desired item detail but don't provide a dollar subtotal for each line item.

Comment: Drupal or not? Wondering if a bit of work to improve Views and line items would give you and others some good outcomes for this

Comment: Looking for a native solution.  We're on Drupal but don't want to be tied to it.

Comment: fair enough. let's see what others have to say

Comment: I am not sure that there is a "Civi" way to sub-total each Line Item grouping (we use Sorting rather than Grouping). But you can export the report to Excel and very quickly Sum the groupings.